# Xamarin.iOS One Signal Notification Extension Service

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, onesignal, ios-extensions

I have been trying to implement the notification badge count that One Signal provides.

I follow their tutorial https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup#section-5-ios-add-the-notification-extension-service

And I also registered the App group in the apple developer portal and added it to the provision profile.

But when I try to deploy I get this error:

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.

I think the problem is that the provision profile I have set in the iOS project doesn't show in the Notification Extension project, so I just set it to Automatic Provisioning. Any idea why the provision profile doesn't show?

Comment: Make sure that the develop team in Info.plist of the  Notification Extension Service is the same with it in Info.plist of your main xamarin.iOS project .

Comment: I set both projects to Automatic Provisioning with the same team, still not working.